# Laravel: Deny empty PUT requests in validation

Tags: laravel, validation, dingo-api

Laravel 5.3's `$api->resource()` routes map PUT requests to the controller's `update` method.

I fail to trigger a validation error when an empty HTTP PUT request is made. My `$this->validate()` rules are all optional, since no field is required in an update.
But I'd really like to let validation fail if the request is empty (`count($request->all() == 0`).

Is there a way to do that with the [in-built validation rules](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation)?

A validation rule of `'*' => 'min:1'` does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not find a working in-built rule, so I registered a custom rule:

```
    \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::extendImplicit(
        'requestnotempty',
        function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
            return count($validator->getData()) !== 0;
        }
    );
```

Then I used it:

```
    $this->validate(
        $request,
        [
            '' => 'requestnotempty',
            //...
        ]
    );
```